# Why I could not knit in RStudio? It's continuously requiring me to update rmarkdown, thoghth it's already the latest version

Tags: r, windows, r-markdown, install.packages

[error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjRD3.png)
Every time when I clicked on 'yes' and update rmarkdown again, it's like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mDzE.png)

My R version is 4.2.2, which is the latest.
I've also tried codes like:
update.packages(rmarkdown)
install.packages("rmarkdown", repos = "https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/all/latest")
install.packages("rmarkdown", lib = "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.2.2/library")
None of them worked.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

That zero exit error typically means that your package was dependent upon the installation of some *other package* that is likely explained in some of the message above.

You should try to scrolling back through to find the othe package which is failing, and resolve its install errors.

You may find that there are several that will need to be resolve to fix the problem.

You must fix them all because that `non-zero exit` means that R did not install the `rMarkdown` package.

Comment: I scrolled back and the error is probably over here: 

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
         binary source needs_compilation
markdown    1.4    1.5             FALSE

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: Hey, sorry about the delay I was in the wilderness (literally) If you have not solved the problem, post the reporting text from the console, including the error, in full. I can try to help you chase it down